# How to instruct linker to consider strong IRQ definition present in static library insteadof weak definition

Tags: usb

We have problem in linking strong USB_IRQ handler.

We have real USB IRQ definition present in a static library.
We are filling .vector table in application startup file (*.s) with handler name and we also have the __weak definition, defined in the same startup file.

While linking we see linker always picks-up weak IRQ definition present in the startup file instead of strong IRQ definition present in the library (*.a).

If we remove weak definition from startup file, the strong definition is considered and it works well.

The problem that we see is, the library file that contains strong definition is not referred in any means from our application, that means, we are not using any functions or structures present in that file.  only, IRQ handler is used and that too it trigger only when there is a hardware event.

We use ARM GNU tool chain, tried multiple options nothing helps.
We went through the internet help, and found few options like, --no_remove and --keep linker options, but, these flags does not seems to be supported.

Please suggest if you have some input in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure that at least one symbol in the same source file as the strong definition gets referenced from your program.  Otherwise, the linker will have no reason to load the object file that contains the IRQ.  So for example you could define some init function in that source file, and call it from your program.

Make sure the IRQ function is declared with `__attribute__((used))` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

The file that has the strong definition is a third party source for us.  We will not be able to modify the source legally and also, we will not be able to add __attribute__((used)) on declaration of the IRQ function.

Is it possible impose such rule during compilation?  either to IRQ function declaration or to the complete object?

Comment: Well, I don't know then, that's a significantly different problem.  If it's proprietary third-party software, they should provide you some support.  Do you even have the source code?  Is it possible you could just include the object file (`*.o`) as an argument to the linker instead of storing it in a `.a` file?  Can you get rid of the weak definition in your project?